# “Only reserved document ids may start with underscore." when trying to use _find

Tags: http, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I'm working with CouchDB and am trying to search a db using _find. I am currently running into the following error:

```
error: 'illegal_docid',
  reason: 'Only reserved document ids may start with underscore.',
  scope: 'couch',
  statusCode: 400,
  request:
   { method: 'POST',
     headers:
      { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        Host: 'example.com',
        Referer: 'https://example.com' },
     uri: 'http://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@206.189.178.130:5984/gc_common/_find',
     body: '{"selector":{"_id":"taglist"}}' },
  headers:
   { date: 'Thu, 25 Jul 2019 22:04:09 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     connection: 'close',
     'cache-control': 'must-revalidate',
     statusCode: 400,
     uri: 'http://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@206.189.178.130:5984/gc_common/_find' },
  errid: 'non_200',
  description: 'couch returned 400' }
```

Comment: What's the version of your CouchDB?

Comment: My CouchDB version is 2.1.1

Comment: Did you get the version from an API call to the same URL? If not, do so.

Comment: How do I get the version from an API call?

Comment: Simply get on the root url. Example GET http://localhost:5984/

Comment: Ok, I made a call to the root url. The version is indeed 2.1.1. I've also tried removing the underscore from the id field in the body, but the error still persists.

Comment: Any relevant in your Couch logs? Using any proxy? Can you try updating?

Comment: How can I access CouchDB logs?

Comment: Ok, I had a look at the DB log (/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.log, and I didn't find anything too useful. The only records found after making _find calls were these: [notice] 2019-08-03T19:31:12.057283Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.8378.1155> -------- 74.105.135.150 - - POST /gc_common/_find 400
[error] 2019-08-03T19:31:12.057451Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.8378.1155> -------- httpd 400 error response:
 {"error":"illegal_docid","reason":"Only reserved document ids may start with underscore."}

Comment: And in the UI you see the Mango editor? Can you query it?